# Formula for skewed bell curve

Tags: normal-distribution

I can plot a bell curve using the formula:
$$
Y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi S^2} } e^{ -\frac{(X-A)^2}{(2S)^2} }
$$
where A=mean and S=standard deviation. This is obviously on an X,Y plot.

I want to add a skew value of -1 to 1 where 0 means no skew (a normal distribution). Is there a commonly accepted formula that will skew the bell curve?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution

Comment: What does a skew value of $1$ mean?  What about $0.324$?

Comment: @Randall A 1 means it has the max positive skew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple, well-known modification to skew a normal distribution as follows,

$$Y_k(X) = Y(X) + k\frac{dY(X)}{dX}$$

where $k$ is the skew parameter to regulate the amount of skews and

$$\frac{dY(X)}{dX}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi S^2} } e^{ -\frac{(X-A)^2}{(2S)^2} }\left(-\frac{X-A}{2S^2}\right)
$$

This is often used in financial modeling, and it preserves the unit cumulative integration.

Comment: I know it isn't truly part of the question, but can you also list exactly what dY(X)/dX is? With X in the esponent of e, differentiation isn't so straight forward for someone who can program, but isn't really a math person.

Comment: @kainaw - see the edit

Comment: Great. I thought that it was too simple when I did it. I'm adding this to my notes and making a big note that the 2 in the denominator of the added part is NOT sqaured. Was (expanded) 2*2*s*s, but the 2 in the numerator canceled out one of the 2's, so you just 2*s*s. In programming, it is easy to make a mistake because 2 in the denominator of the exponent is squared.

Comment: @Quanto that's a neat trick. Can you please point me to a reference (e.g., paper, book) that introduced or used this approximation?

Comment: @feluda I have not done financial modeling for a while and can’t seem to find a handy reference